# Post fails with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to post data with node.js. I have written the following code and installed MySQL support via npm, but I failed to `Post` to database .

I am using standart express backend

Here is my code users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host:'localhost',
  user:'alp',
  password:'******',
  database :'diablo'
});



/* post users listing.  connection.connect(); */

router.post('/', function(req, res,next) {
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;


connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?)" ,[username,password], function(err,rows,fields) {
if (err) console.log(err);

if (rows.length > 0) {
  res.send({'success':true,'message':rows[0].username });
} else {
  res.send({'success':false,'message' : 'User not found , please try again'});
}
});

});


module.exports = router;
```

Error Message

> Response {   "_bodyInit": "{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"User not
>   found , please try again\"}",   "_bodyText":
>   "{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"User not found , please try
>   again\"}",   "heade

What is my mistake?

By the way I checked other headlines. ı did not find it

Comment: Can you confirm that the credentials you passed in are actually being passed in/valid?

Comment: If `username` and `password` is correct then what is the value of `rows`?

Comment: @abdulbarik if the query passes, then the value of rows will be an array of objects for every matched user.

Comment: My concern is what is the result after executing the query, is  he getting expected result or empty array with those infos?

Comment: @abdulbarik read the response object, the query returned an empty array.

Comment: I can confirm credentials is valid . Rows value is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are attempting to retrieve username and password from **req.body** object, and you failed to require **body-parser** in order to be able to do that, hence your username and password are undefined and your query fails to find the corresponding user.

To install the **body-parser** module just type npm install --s body-parser and then require it in your users.js file.

Comment: If `body-parser` wasn't used, `req.body` wouldn't have existed at all and referencing `req.body.username` would have thrown an error.

Comment: I added body-parser . Nothing is changed . I still have same error .

Comment: Somehow I can't fetch data from mysql .

Comment: Could you please post server-side log also? It may happen that your query is throwing and error but since in your code you are not returning after the error you are still running the rest of the method and entering the second if statement.